Understanding the proof of Giraud's Theorem
I am trying to understand the proof of a lemma of Giraud's Theorem in Lurie's notes on categorical logic:
https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture10-Giraud.pdf
I am confused by the proof of Lemma 7. The statement, saying that:

Let $\{U_i \to X\}_{i\in I}$ be a covering in $X$ (not necessarily between objects of $\cal C$). Then the induced map $\coprod h_{U_i} \to h_X$ is an effective epimorphism in $Shv(\cal C)$.

I am not quite comfortable about the derivation between the last two sentences:

By construction, for each
pair $(i, j)$, the image $s_{i,j} \in h_X(V_{i,j} )$ of $s$ belongs to the image of the map $h_{U_i}(V_{i,j} ) → h_X(V_{i,j} )$. Allowing $\cal C$
and $s$ to vary, we conclude that the maps $\{h_{U_i} → h_X\}$ are a covering of $h_X$ in the topos $Sh(\cal C)$.

The first sentence just says each $s_{ij}:V_{ij}\to X$ factories through $U_i$ as $V_{ij}\to {U_i\times_X C}\to U_i\to X$, but how can we drive the argument home and conclude $\{h_{U_i} → h_X\}$ is a cover? Here I believe it refers to the definition in the same link https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/278xnotes/Lecture10-Giraud.pdf in Definition 1.
